# Web Scrapping dynamic content with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would simply like to get the Open Price of a stock with BeautifulSoup or Selenium is okay but i keep getting just the html tag for it and not the actually price i want

```
# <div class="tv-fundamental-block__value js-symbol-open">33931.0</div>
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/PEPPERSTONE-US30/')
response = url.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
# print(soup.prettify())
open = soup.find('div', {'class': 'js-symbol-open'})
print(open)
```

The 33931.0 is the price id like to see in my terminal but i still dont get it

Using selenium ive only gotten the page i already know where i am getting the data from.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the text content of the element using BeautifulSoup, use the .text property of the element:

```
open = soup.find('div', {'class': 'js-symbol-open'}).text
print(open)
```

In selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/PEPPERSTONE-US30/')

open_price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.js-symbol-open').text
print(open_price)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.js-symbol-open')` is deprecated in selenium4, use newer syntax `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By; driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.js-symbol-open')`

Comment: I get this <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="25b611aedf0c9a709503a4c6d6f8814d", element="1ecd6c18-aece-4d8f-94a7-dcb151410b7e")> in the console